# Error: Cannot find module './lib/_stream_readable.js'

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to launch the app on Android device, but I've faced one problem.
I run the following command:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

and get the error:

```
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './lib/_stream_readable.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
```

Did anybody face the same problem?